# Search all unique terms from a given query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search for all the unique names in the index test_nested.

**GET test_nested/_mappings**

```
{
  "test_nested": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "group": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "user": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**GET test_nested/_search**

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_nested",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "AWG5iVBz4bQsVnslc9gL",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "group": "fans",
          "user": [
            {
              "name": "Linux"
            },
            {
              "name": "Android (operating system)"
            },
            {
              "name": "Widows 10"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_nested",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "AWG5ieKW4bQsVnslc9gM",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "group": "fans",
          "user": [
            {
              "name": "Bitcoin"
            },
            {
              "name": "PHP"
            },
            {
              "name": "Microsoft Windows"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_nested",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "AWG5irrV4bQsVnslc9gN",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "group": "fans",
          "user": [
            {
              "name": "Windows XP"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_nested",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "group": "fans",
          "user": [
            {
              "name": "iOS"
            },
            {
              "name": "Android (operating system)"
            },
            {
              "name": "Widows 10"
            },
            {
              "name": "Widows XP"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**I want all the unique names for a term. i.e. if I search for *"wi*"* then I should get *[Microsoft Windows, Widows 10, Windows XP]***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Hope it helps someone.

```
GET record_new/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "software_tags": {
        "value": "windows"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "software_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "software_tags.keyword",
        "include" : ".*Windows.*",
        "size": 10000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean but I use that query to list all statuses:

```
GET order/default/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "status_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status.keyword",
        "missing": "N/A",
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My model has status field and that query lists all statuses.

This is [bucket aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html)

One of fields in result is: 
*sum_other_doc_count* - Elastic returns the top unique terms. So if you have many different terms then some of them will not appear in the results. This field is a sum of documents which will not be a part of the response.

For *nested* objects try to read and use [Nested Query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)